# cv.glmnet crashing in R studio, when trying to run a multinomial regression with LASSO penalty. Reproducible example provided

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am trying to run `cv.glmnet` with `family="multinomial"`.

However whenever I run it, RStudio crashes. I have also tried just running it from the command line, but this then just quits R.
I have also triws RStudio server but this crashes as well.

My response classes are given in matrix from and I have a corresponding feature matrix.
Below I give the code, with the dataset hosted on GitHub:

```
# Loading datasets:
load(url("https://github.com/DylanDijk/RepoA/blob/main/reprod_features.rda?raw=true"))
load(url("https://github.com/DylanDijk/RepoA/blob/main/reprod_response.rda?raw=true"))

# Training the model:
model_multinom_cv = glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = reprod_features,  y = reprod_response,
                                      family = "multinomial", alpha = 1)
```

Comment: Does the issue also occur with `glmnet` and a given lambda, i.e., with the full data and without the cross validation?

Comment: It works for ```model_multinom_cv = glmnet::glmnet(x = reprod_features,  y = reprod_response, family = "multinomial", alpha = 1, lambda =2 )```.

Comment: I suspect 43 responses is simply too much. It runs fine with 15 responses. You could try supplying your own lambda sequence.

Comment: How would you recommend going about selecting a lambda sequence.

Comment: @Roland what do you think is causing it to crash. Is too much memory being used? I just think it is strange that it is causing RStudio to crash and not giving out a warning message in the console instead.

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't look like R ran out of memory on my system. It might be worth a report to the package maintainer. Such a crash is always a bug.

Comment: Ok I will do that, also just to confirm does running the full example also crash on your machine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it does crash on my system.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this issue. I am one of the maintainers of `glmnet`. I took a look at the example and found that there was a subtle bug in the code. We will release a new version of `glmnet` soon with this patch, so keep an eye out for version `4.1-5`!

Comment: Ok great thank you @James Yang, do you know approximately when this will be released?

Comment: Unclear, but if you want a quick and dirty fix right now, you can modify the source code. It's literally one character change. You can clone the [mirror](https://github.com/cran/glmnet). Then change [this line](https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/daf551b69ae17b08774b81dddbd535b59a66f172/src/glmnetpp/include/glmnetpp_bits/elnet_point/internal/binomial_base.hpp#L1009) to `a[i] < a[j]`. Use `devtools` package in `R` and run `install()` in the root directory of the repo to install from source. This should overwrite your original installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JamesYang this now works for me. However, I have some convergence issues now when trying to train my model. I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486402/cv-glmnet-does-not-converge-for-certain-lamda-values), and was wondering if you had any advise. Thanks again.