# cv.glmnet does not converge for certain lamda values

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am training a multinomial regression model using `cv.glmnet`, and the number of features and number of classes I have been using has been increasing. On previous versions of my training set, where I had fewer features and classes, my model converged for all lambdas after increasing the value of `maxit`.

However, with the training data I am using now, I get the following errors even when I increase `maxit = 10^7`.

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: from glmnet C++ code (error code -13); Convergence for 13th lambda
> value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger
> lambdas returned
>
> 2: from glmnet C++ code (error code -14); Convergence for 14th lambda
> value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger
> lambdas returned
>
> 3: from glmnet C++ code (error code -13);
> Convergence for 13th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000
> iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned
> .
> .
> .

```
Here is code that recreates these warnings:

load(url("https://github.com/DylanDijk/RepoA/blob/main/reprod_features.rda?raw=true"))
load(url("https://github.com/DylanDijk/RepoA/blob/main/reprod_response.rda?raw=true"))

# Training the model:
model_multinom_cv = glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = reprod_features,  y = reprod_response,
                                      family = "multinomial", alpha = 1)
```

**I was wondering if anyone had any advise on trying to get a model to converge for all lambda values in the path.**

Some options I have been thinking that I will try:

- Would an option be to change some of the internal parameters as
  listed in the [glmnet
  vignette](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf#page=36)
- Or to select a lambda sequence myself and then increase `maxit`
  further. I have tried `maxit = 10^8` without defining a lambda
  sequence but this did not train after multiple hours.
- Choose a subset of the features, I have trained the model with a small subset of the features and it the model converged for more `lambda` values.

  - But I would rather use all of the features so want to explore whether there are other options first.

## Lambda path returned

Below is the lambda path returned after training my model:

```
> model_multinom_cv$glmnet.fit

Call:  glmnet(x = train_sparse, y = train_res, trace.it = 1, 
              family = "multinomial", alpha = 1) 

   Df  %Dev  Lambda
1   0  0.00 0.17730
2   1  1.10 0.16150
3   2  1.88 0.14720
4   5  4.72 0.13410
5   8  8.52 0.12220
6  14 13.49 0.11130
7  21 19.90 0.10150
8  27 25.83 0.09244
9  31 30.63 0.08423
10 36 34.56 0.07674
11 41 38.61 0.06993
12 45 41.89 0.06371
```

Comment: Can you provide the sequence of lambdas returned?

Comment: @JamesYang I have added a section at the bottom of my question. I show the output of ```model$glmnet.ft```

Comment: @JamesYang have I shown the correct output?

Comment: Hi Dylan, yes you did. It's difficult to diagnose these convergence problems, since it's very dependent on the dataset. One thing you could try is to feed in your own lambda sequence. The first 12 can be the same as shown, but try making the 13th one much closer to the 12th one. Warm starting only works well when the lambdas are close together and it may be the case that the lambdas are not close enough.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Whilst thinking about reducing the jump between lambda values, I saw that there was an option to increase the number of lambda values used. I increased `nlambda = 200`, from the default value of `100` and this now works really well. Thanks again.